# ODBC_Fetch_array if loop works, while loop doesnt

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop, odbc

I'm trying to get data from a database code:

```
$carsql = "SELECT history.partno
           FROM history 
           WHERE history.vm = 'TT' 
               AND history.status = 0
               AND history.voucherno = '$voucherno'";
$carinfo = odbc_exec($db,$carsql);              
if($car1 = odbc_fetch_array($carinfo)){
    while ($car = odbc_fetch_array($carinfo)){
```

The SQL returns rows when I manually execute the SQL also, the IF loop gives a positive result.  When I do the same execution in the While row it stops working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if condition is useless, just omit it.
With the if line gone, the while loop will only begin if you have results in the array anyhow.